# screen on tuch point shown and record the data of xy tuch

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, android-fragments

I'm creating a simple UI for graph plotted by algorithm on android where you touch a certain part of the screen to generate random points on the screen. My main question is it possible to just split the screen into 4 quadrants and recognize when the quadrants were touched?

Comment: It will be easy to do with a Relative Layout : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    final int screenWidth = size.x;
    final int screenHeight = size.y;

    root.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (event.getX() < screenWidth / 2) {
                    if (event.getY() < screenHeight / 2) {
                        // you are 1. area
                    } else {
                        // you are 2. area
                    }
                } else {
                    if (event.getY() < screenHeight / 2) {
                        // you are 3. area
                    } else {
                        // you are 4. area
                    }
                } 
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take the the position and the size of the screen and easily calculate that.
this function to take the position of touch

```
//function to take the position of touch
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       int x = event.getX();
       int y = event.getY();
       return true;
    }
//function to get screen size
     private void setScreenSize() {
            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);//need context
             height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
             width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        }
```